# How to Generate Individual DLL/aseembly file for Areas in asp.net core 2.0?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I am beginner at asp.net core 2.0. I would like to generate separate dll file for individual areas. If someone knows how to do that configuration in startup.cs please let me know.

[How to separate asp.net core mvc project into multiple assembly (.dll)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56185350/how-to-separate-asp-net-core-mvc-project-into-multiple-assembly-dll)

i tried above link but it wont work for areas.

Comment: try to avoid to post links, they can expire and try to be more specific

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. One project roughly equals one DLL. If you want the areas to each be a different DLL, then they need to be separate projects, Razor Class Libraries (RCLs) specifically. You can create an RCL for each, put the area in that, and then reference the RCL from any other project you need it in.

Comment: Thanks !! Its Really Great Help.