# Reference directly a Razor Class Library assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, razor-pages, razor-class-library

I'm working on a web application where pages need to be populated from other projects. I was hoping to use a Razor Class Library (RCL) for that. 
The documentation states that [a RCL can be referenced only as a project reference or a nuget package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/ui-class?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#reference-rcl-content). I was hoping it would just be a shortcut to make sure developers went the recommended way. Unfortunately, if I directly reference the two generated assemblies from my RCL project (`MyProject.dll` and `MyProject.Views.dll`), it doesn't work. It works only if I add a project reference to the RCL project.

The company I work for has a custom build pipeline, and for reasons outside of my control I can only directly reference assemblies.

I've spent some time comparing the output of the compilation when using direct references and project references, but I couldn't find a difference. **Does anybody know why direct references don't work for RCL?** If I understand what the difference is, I should be able to work my way from there.

As a bonus, is somebody aware of a workaround? Creating a `CompiledRazorAssemblyPart` works (as described in [Loading Razor Class Libraries as plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50762385/loading-razor-class-libraries-as-plugins/50763775#50763775)), but I'd rather not have to manually search for the assemblies.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you find any workaround or a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Put below code on Startup.cs

```
var assemblies = new string[] { "APP.Plugins.Test" };

        services
           .AddMvc()
           .ConfigureApplicationPartManager(apm =>
           {

               foreach (var assemblyFile in assemblies)
               {

                   //main assembly
                   var assembly = Assembly.Load(assemblyFile);
                   apm.ApplicationParts.Add(new AssemblyPart(assembly));

                   //view assembly
                   var assemblyView = Assembly.Load(assemblyFile+".Views");
                   apm.ApplicationParts.Add(new CompiledRazorAssemblyPart(assemblyView));                     
               }
           });
```

Comment: Microsoft typically has great documentation, but they are completely missing a section on dynamically loading RCL projects. No mention of CompiledRazorAssemblyPart. Thank you for this!!!